# Mandar uma List<Entity> no Redirect

Tags: jsf, java-ee

Tenho uma List e preciso mandar ela para outra página para preencher uma table, quanto o redirect acaba a página carrega só que a table não preenche por que a List foi esvaziada, como mantenho ela com as informações?

MinhaBean

```
@ManagedBean(name = "lotesEnvBean")
@ViewScoped
public class LoteEnviadoBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private LoteEnvRepository envRepository;

    private List<LoteEnvEntity> lotesEnviados;
    private List<LoteEnvEntity> lotesSelecionados = new ArrayList<LoteEnvEntity>();
    private List<LoteEnvDetalheEntity> lotesEnvDetalhe;
    private Collection<Object> selecao;

    private Date dataDe;
    private Date dataAte;
    private Flash flash;

    private UIComponent component;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.lotesEnviados = envRepository.findall();
    }

    public void selectionListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        AbstractExtendedDataTable dataTable = (AbstractExtendedDataTable) event
            .getComponent();
        Object originalKey = dataTable.getRowKey();
        lotesSelecionados.clear();
        for (Object selectionKey : selecao) {
            dataTable.setRowKey(selectionKey);
            if (dataTable.isRowAvailable()) {
                lotesSelecionados.add((LoteEnvEntity) dataTable.getRowData());
            }
        }
        dataTable.setRowKey(originalKey);
    }

    public Collection<Object> getSelecao() {
        return selecao;
    }

    public void setSelecao(Collection<Object> selecao) {
        this.selecao = selecao;
    }

    public void setSelectionItems(List<LoteEnvEntity> selectionItems) {
        this.lotesSelecionados = selectionItems;
    }

    public List<LoteEnvEntity> getLotesEnviados() {
        return lotesEnviados;
    }

    public void setLotesEnviados(List<LoteEnvEntity> lotesEnviados) {
        this.lotesEnviados = lotesEnviados;
    }

    public List<LoteEnvEntity> getLotesSelecionados() {
        return lotesSelecionados;
    }

    public Date getDataDe() {
        return dataDe;
    }

    public void setDataDe(Date dataDe) {
        this.dataDe = dataDe;
    }

    public Date getDataAte() {
        return dataAte;
    }

    public void setDataAte(Date dataAte) {
        this.dataAte = dataAte;
    }

    public void setLotesSelecionados(List<LoteEnvEntity> lotesSelecionados) {
        this.lotesSelecionados = lotesSelecionados;
    }

    public List<LoteEnvDetalheEntity> getLotesEnvDetalhe() {
        return lotesEnvDetalhe;
    }

    public void setLotesEnvDetalhe(List<LoteEnvDetalheEntity> lotesEnvDetalhe) {
        this.lotesEnvDetalhe = lotesEnvDetalhe;
    }

    public UIComponent getComponent() {
        return component;
    }

    public void setComponent(UIComponent component) {
        this.component = component;
    }

    public Flash getFlash() {
        return flash;
    }

    public void setFlash(Flash flash) {
        this.flash = flash;
    }

    public List<LoteEnvEntity> findByDate() {
        this.lotesEnviados = envRepository.findallByDate(this.dataDe,
            this.dataAte);
        return this.lotesEnviados;
    }

    public String exibirLotesSelecionados() {

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        System.out.println("#########################################################----" + this.lotesSelecionados.size());
        if(this.lotesSelecionados.size() <= 0) {
            context.addMessage(component.getClientId(), new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Erro","Deve-se selecionar ao menos um lote."));
            return "";
        }

        this.lotesEnvDetalhe = this.envRepository.exibirLotesSelecionados(this.lotesSelecionados);


        if (this.lotesEnvDetalhe.size() > 0)
            return "lotesEnviadosListagem.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
        else
            context.addMessage(component.getClientId(), new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Erro","Não foi possível exibir o(s) lote(s)."));

            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Comecei a trabalhar com Java EE essa semana, antes disso tive pouco contato com desenvolvimento web, e estou tendo que dar os meus pulos aqui.
Nesse caso por usar o   FlashContet então?

Comment: Cadê seu managed bean?? Basta colocar os gets e sets nele e referenciá-lo na página

Comment: Você pode usar o `FacesContext.getInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash()` para acessar o `Flash Scope`. Acessar tanto antes do redirect para enviar a lista, quanto no `PostConstruct` para recuperá-la.

Comment: @Wakim obrigado! teria um exemplo XD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `Flash Scope` é frequentemente usado quando se quer manter um dado acessível apenas até o próximo *request*. O que é vantajoso se, ao final de uma ação de um `Managed Bean`, você redireciona para uma outra página e precisa passar dados para essa nova página.

Durante a ação do `Bean`, antes de ocorrer a navegação, você pode armazenar dados no `Flash Scope` e recuperá-los na próxima requisição, a que irá de fato renderizar o conteúdo da `View` que você redirecionou.

Os dados guardados no `Flash Scope` só vão durar até o próximo *request*, após isso será apagado. Isso ocorre porque o armazenamento é feito na sessão e depois removido ao final do *request* subsequente.

Exemplo prático:

```
public String exibirLotesSelecionados() {

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    if(this.lotesSelecionados.size() <= 0) {
        context.addMessage(component.getClientId(), new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Erro","Deve-se selecionar ao menos um lote."));

        return "";
    }

    this.lotesEnvDetalhe = this.envRepository.exibirLotesSelecionados(this.lotesSelecionados);


    if (this.lotesEnvDetalhe.size() > 0) {
         // Adiciono a lista no Flash Scope para o proximo Bean recuperar
        context.getExternalContext().getFlash().put("lista", lotesSelecionados);
        return "lotesEnviadosListagem.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    } else {
        context.addMessage(component.getClientId(), new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Erro","Não foi possível exibir o(s) lote(s)."));
    }

    return "";
}
```

No `PostConstruct` do `Managed Bean` da `lotesEnviadosListagem.xhtml`

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    List<LoteEnvDetalheEntity> lotesEnviados = (List<LoteEnvDetalheEntity>) FacesContext.getInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().get("lista");

    // Guardar a lista para usar no dataTable
}
```

Mais detalhes na documentação do [`Flash`](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/javadocs/javax/faces/context/Flash.html)