# Dúvidas com FlashScope

Tags: jsf

Olá, tudo bom? Estou com uma dúvida em relação ao uso do flashScope e gostaria da ajuda de vocês.

Quando colocamos um atributo dentro do FlashScope, por quanto tempo o mesmo fica lá? Digo, os atributos da sessão ficam até a sessão cair e etc, o view se mantém enquanto não fizermos nenhum redirect, mas e o Flash? Precisamos remover o atributo ?

Nesse blog [(link)](http://uaihebert.com/jsf-exibindo-objeto-e-mensagens-apos-redirect/) o autor faz a seguinte citação:

> "O escopo Flash nada mais faz do que guarda o objeto como se fosse sessão. Atenção para o fato de que após a sua utilização o objeto “user” será removido do escopo."

Então quando eu fizer colocar um atributo e depois fazer um get nele, automaticamente será destruido?

Alguém pode me esclarecer um pouco?

***EDIT:***

Acabei tentando me aventurar e consegui resultado bons, só que tem algo que ta me irritando que são as mensagem de ***WARNING*** que o JSF manda:

> Apr 24, 2015 5:31:10 PM com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash setCookie
>   WARNING: JSF1095: The response was already committed by the time we tried to set the outgoing cookie for the flash.  Any values stored to the flash will not be available on the next request.

Tem como desabilitar isso?

**EDIT2:** Aqui está o código que estou usando:

Esse é meu métedo que inseri e pega do flashScope:

```
    public static Object getFlashAttribute(String attributeName) {
    return getExternalContext().getFlash().get(attributeName);
}

public static void setFlashAttribute(String key, Object value) {
    getExternalContext().getFlash().put(key, value);
}
```

Aqui é onde eu coloco um objeto no flash scope e faço o redirect:

```
    public String openPostConf() {
    if (selectedFeeds.size() != 1) {
        strFeedMessage = "";
        return "";
    }
    Feed feedEdition = selectedFeeds.get(0);
    LOGGER.info("Editando conteudo: " + feedEdition);
    JSFHelper.setFlashAttribute("feedToEdit", feedEdition);
    markAll = false;
    return "toEditFeed";
}
```

e aqui é onde eu recebo, no construtor do meu outro managedBean:

```
public PostConfMB() {
    feedForEdition = (Feed) JSFHelper.getFlashAttribute("feedToEdit");
}
```

Comment: Acho que essa [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39490) pode ajudar a entender o comportamento do FlashScope. Pelo menos na implementação do projeto Mojarra, o FlashScope é gerenciado via Cookies pelo **ELFlash**, feito para manter um escopo em req. do tipo **Post-Redirect-Get**. Se observar uma req. onde foi usado o Flash, você irá ver um cookie chamado "csfcfc" que é, a grosso modo, uma chave de um Mapa que mantém o escopo Flash. O problema é um Cookie está sendo criado após a req. ser "commitada", se puder identificar o código que gera o warning, poderia incluí-lo na pergunta?

Comment: Oi Wakim, obrigado pela sua atenção, adicionei alguns códigos que uso para manipular o flash scope, muito obrigado

Comment: Conseguiu sanar sua dúvida @PauloGustavo ? se sim, poste como resposta para ajudar outros usuarios.